# Distinct values list

Tags: c#, list, unique

I am trying to get Locations out of a List locations. All of the values has to be unique from eachother in sequence.

I ask myself what I can do best.

Location contains a Latitude and a longitude.

```
List<Location> locations;

Location a,b,c,d;
a = locations[....]
b = locations[....]
c = locations[....]
d = locations[....]
```

So how should I give a,b,c and d all unique values, so that there's no Location equal to each other?

Comment: What kind of information is within the `Location` class (i.e *show* us)?

Comment: I location your class or part of a library? I want to know if you can override .Equals and .GetHashcode if you need to!

Comment: In general, if I understand you correctly, use LINQ Distinct method (providing your `IEqualityComparer` or make Location implementing  `IEquatable<T>` interface).

Comment: var query = (from loc in location
            select loc).Distinct();

Comment: Can someone maybe show me an example?

Comment: List<Location> result = locations.Distinct().ToList();

Answer (score 1):

You should override `Equals` and `GetHashCode` in your class, for example:

```
public class Location
{
    public int Latitude { get; set; }
    public int Longitude { get; set; }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if(obj == null)return false;
        if(object.ReferenceEquals(this, obj)) return true;
        Location l2 = obj as Location;
        if(l2 == null) return false;
        return Latitude == l2.Latitude && Longitude == l2.Longitude;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        unchecked // Overflow is fine, just wrap
        {
            int hash = 17;
            hash = hash * 23 + Latitude.GetHashCode();
            hash = hash * 23 + Longitude.GetHashCode();
            return hash;
        }
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("{0},{1}", Latitude, Longitude);
    }
}
```

Now you can already use `Enumerable.Distinct` to remove duplicates:

```
var uniqeLocations = locations.Distinct().ToList();
```

Comment: But if I create this overrided method, should I call it for all of the locations I already created? How do I have to use this method?

Comment: You don't call it, when you call `.Distinct` it'll call it *for you*. MSDN has good documentationn of equality comparers: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms224763(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @Klyner: i'm not sure if you've seen the last code snippet in my answer. `Enumerable.Distinct` has an overload that takes a custom `IEqualityComparer<T>` instance which is another approach. But if you have already overridden `Equals` (override always also `GetHashCode`) then you don't need it. `locations.Distinct().ToList()` does already what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `Union` method on array instances to merge distinct items (remember to include `using System.Linq` to get access to Linq specific extension methods):

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

namespace DistinctValues
{
    public struct Location
    {
        public Location(double longitude, double latitude) : this()
        {
            this.Longitude = longitude;
            this.Latitude = latitude;
        }
        public double Longitude { get; set; }
        public double Latitude { get; set; }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return string.Format("Longitude: {0}, Latitude={1}", this.Longitude, this.Latitude);
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var a = new Location[] 
            { 
                new Location(123.456, 456.789),
                new Location(123.456, 456.789),
                new Location(234.567, 890.123),
            };
            var b = new Location[]
            {
                new Location(123.456, 456.789),
                new Location(890.123, 456.789),
            };

            // Join array a and b. Uses union to pick distinct items from joined arrays
            var result = a.Union(b);

            // Dump result to console
            foreach(var item in result)
                Console.WriteLine(item);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Seems not that hard to implement. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want or can't change implementation of your `Location` class, and you need to get distinct locations, you can group them by latitude and longitude and then select first location from each group (all locations in group will have same latitude and longitude):

```
var distinctLocations = from l in locations
                        group l by new { l.Latitude, l.Longitude } into g
                        select g.First();
```

But of course, if that is not single place where you need to compare locations, you should go with @Tim Schmelter solution.

UPDATE: Getting unique random locations:

```
Random rnd = new Random();

List<Location> uniqueRandomLocations =
      locations.GroupBy(l => new { l.Latitude, l.Longitude })
               .Select(g => g.First())
               .OrderBy(l => rnd.Next())
               .Take(N)
               .ToList();
```

Comment: Seems a lot of time to care. What do you select with g.First()?

Comment: @Klyner that will be first `Location` object from group (thus group always contains at least on location). So this query gives you only locations with unique latitude-longitude coordinates.

Comment: I have to get random locations from the 'main' list, which are all unique to eachother. Is it hard to change it to a function that saved these locations in a list? Thanks for your help

Comment: @Klyner sure it is possible - you can write query which selects N distinct locations in random order (you still can use `Distinct()` instead of grouping by latitude and longitude if you'll add Equals and GetHashCode implementations